# RSpec should_receive is execting the original method in a Mailer even though I don't tell it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm testing one of my mailers, and I have a controller test that just asserts that the mailer gets called (very similar to [the example from email_spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec#testing-in-isolation)).

```
# spec/controllers/friendships_controller_spec.rb

it "sends an email when someone sends you a contact request" do
  NotificationMailer.any_instance.should_receive(:contact_request).with(default_user, user)
  xhr :post, :create, {:friendship => {:friend_id => user.id}}
end
```

This spec fails due to a a variable being set to `nil` in the template for contact_request.   So it seems like... the `contact_request` method is actually executing and rendering its template, even though I have the method mocked up.  How come?

If it makes any difference, the template renders just fine in the actual application - the variable is only set to nil in this particular spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `any_instance` from the stub chain?  Isn't it called in your code via:  `NotificationMailer.contact_request`?  `any_instance` is assuming it was called on an instance of the class, not on the class itself.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's exactly the problem.  It's not letting me mark your answer as correct yet, but I will in a minute.

Comment: I guess I just assumed I should stub the instance method since that's how you actually define it in your mailer, but of course you call it as a class method.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that's confusing.  Rails does some weird things :p

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was mocking up the method for an *instance* of NotificationMailer, but of course you actually call it on the *class*.  It looks like ActionMailer::Base is doing some [method_missing magic](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L485) to let you call this as a class method, even though it's defined as an instance method.

The solution is just to call `should_receive` on the class, not the instance.

```
 NotificationMailer.should_receive(:contact_request)
```